# Complex matrix 2x2 eigenvalues determination.

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So i have a matrix A:

\begin{pmatrix}
i & i\bar i \\ 
1-i &\bar i 
\end{pmatrix}

How can i calculate the eigenvalues of a complex matrix like this? I already know how to do if the matrix is not complex, but in complex field?

Using the standard method for R field i got:

$p(A)$$=x^2-2ix+i$

So $P(x)$=$0$ for:

$x=i+2i^2=i-4$ ...and...

$x=i-2i^2=i+4$

Wich seems pretty clear results. Is this method legit? And if i want to calculate the relative eigenspaces of this eigenvalues i just need to use the same method of the R field?

Comment: Your term $-2ix$ is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. All of the calculations are equivalent in all fields, not just $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So if my calculations are correct $i-4$ and $i+4$ are my two complex eigenvalues? (they are wrong i think)

Comment: As @Bernard noted your calculations aren't correct, but that is a different story :)

Comment: Thanks to you and Bernard. This site is amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Note $\;i \bar i=1$, so t the  characteristic polynomial is
$$\begin{vmatrix}i-\lambda&1\\1-i&-i-\lambda\end{vmatrix}=\lambda^2+i,$$
so the eigenvalues are the square roots of $-i$.

Comment: Those calculations... ...thanks... :D

Comment: What? The square roots of $-i$?

Comment: are $\pm$ (1-i)/sqrt2 (if im not wrong)

Comment: Yes. It's easy with the exponential form.